# Symfony 5 no me carga la pantalla de bienvenida

Tags: symfony, symfony5

acabo de crear un proyecto symfony con:
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton nameProject
pero no me abre el proyecto por la web
alguien sabe por que sucede esto?

Nota: ya limpie la cache del navegador[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor realiza tu pregunta con más especificaciones, fundamenta tu pregunta con logs, sistema operativo, programas, consola de navegador (log), versión d composer y terminal

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es muy sencillo, creo un proyecto con el comando:
"composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton Proyecto"
y no me sale la pantalla de bienvenida, solo me dice:
La conexión ha sido reiniciada

La conexión al servidor fue reiniciada mientras la página se cargaba.

    El sitio podría estar no disponible temporalmente o demasiado ocupado. Vuelva a intentarlo en unos momentos.
    Si no puede cargar ninguna página, compruebe la conexión de red de su equipo.
    Si su equipo o red están protegidos por un cortafuegos o proxy, asegúrese de que Firefox tiene permiso para acceder a la web.

Comment: Estoy usando:
xampp 3.3.0
symfony cli 5.4.2
composer 2.3.2
y tengo configurado mi virtual host tambien
Nota: es un proyecto recien instalado via composer y no carga la pantalla de bienvenida